# Предупреждение в VS в проекте .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, .net-core

Предупреждение появляется при использовании любого типа из BCL в проектах .NET Core. О чем говорит это предупреждение и как это исправить?

> "При предположении, что ссылка на сборку "System.Runtime,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a",
>   используемая "System.Collections", совпадает с удостоверением
>   "System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"для "System.Runtime", возможно,
>   потребуется задать политику среды выполнения"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: “We don’t care about warnings. We only care about errors.” - это шутка ))

Comment: Попробуйте обновить Core

Comment: @eastwing, вроде бы помогло)

Comment: @Qutrix Ответ оформлять, или ещё есть сомнения?

Comment: @eastwing, можно оформить)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET Core SDK в настоящий момент устанавливается и обновляется отдельно от Visual Studio. Когда вы обновляете VS, с ним обновляются модули, библиотеки, сигнатуры, и т.д. - а Core об этом "не знает", так как его никто не обновлял.

Для устранения предупреждений, вам нужно скачать и установить [последнюю версию Core](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowsvs2015)

При этом, обратите внимание, старая версия не удалится - и её не следует удалять вручную, поскольку проекты, созданные для предыдущей версии Core продолжат работать именно на этой версии. Проект можно обновить, но если вы работаете в команде, это может привести к необходимости экстренно обновлять Core у всех членов команды.